# angular2 pagination error, no exported member 'PaginationControlsCmp'

Tags: angular, pagination

I am working on adding pagination in my API result. For this I have install "Ng2-pagination", form this url "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-paginate",
But whenever I hit `npm start`, It's gives me following error.

```
app/blog.component.ts(6,23): error TS2305: Module '"/var/www/html/test/ng/node_modules/ng2-pagination/index"' has no exported member 'PaginationControlsCmp'.
```

app/blog.component.ts(13,3): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; providers: (typeof PageService | typeof PaginationServic...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.

Comment: show code of `blog.component.ts`. Also from error `'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.` it look like you are using `directives` in `@Component` decorator which is deprecated now

Comment: i think you have to try https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination  and follow the guide for it

Comment: "http://pastebin.com/DUVc6s9E" my blog code.

Comment: I have tried that documentation but it's giving me again error "https://unsee.cc/gedobizu/"

Answer (score 0):

In latest Angular release `directives` and `pipes` are deprecated on `@Component` metadata. You have to provide your all `directives` and `pipes` inside `declarations` metadata of your `@NgModule` metadata.

So as per [simple-example](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination#simple-example) of `ng2 pagination` you have to import `Ng2PaginationModule` inside yout `AppModule`.

You can check [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) for more detail about `NgModule`.